# How to use a local version of openMP? (GOMP)

Tags: gcc, parallel-processing, openmp, gnu, libgomp

I'd like to bring up some changes (just some prints momentarily) to the GOMP library that I've downloaded from the [git repo](https://github.com/gcc-mirror/gcc.git%5C) but seems like what I'm doing is not really effective because there's no print when execute my code.

What I've tried to do after downloading GCC and build it in a `build/` folder is calling `make -j'nproc'` and then `make install` from here I tried to use my version of GCC by `gcc/build/install/gcc -o test - test.c` end it worked, so I started to modify the LIBGOM target.c file and put some print in a function I'm quite sure is called (checked by [callgrind](https://valgrind.org/docs/manual/cl-manual.html)) "GOMP_target_ext" so I called again those 2 make commands and compile again but my changes didn't have any impact on it. so I tried to call `gcc/build/install/bin/gcc -o test  -fopenmp test.c` and this didn't change much too.
I thought could be the way I call OpenMP in my code so I've changed `#include "omp.h"` to `#include <omp.h>` but nothing again. what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Unix/Linux you can use the [`LD_PRELOAD`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/426230/what-is-the-ld-preload-trick) environment variable to force loading your library other libraries are loaded by `ld`. With weak linking you can even override symbols from a library that is loaded later (e.g. your own `malloc`).